# Docker sets that both the container system and the host system are ubuntu

Tags: docker, ubuntu, db2, redhat

**I usually need to use the db2 database for development,but when I pull the db2 image from docker,I pull the image core distribution as Red Hat, and the distribution I need is ubuntu, how to solve this problem.**[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMKSp.jpg)

Comment: Please don't include images in questions when you can copy-and-paste text. Images may not outlive questions and it makes feedback more difficult (since we can't copy-and-paste text).

Comment: You don't include details of the pull command so it's unclear which container image you're using. It's unsurprising that IBM provides DB2 container images using Red Hat (an IBM company) as the OS. Why do you think the container image OS should be Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out by DazWilkin it is not clear which image you are using, but the official images are most likely all going to be based on RHEL, for the aforementioned reasons (Red Hat being part of IBM). At least all the images that I could find doing a quick search on hub.docker.com and quay.io seem to be based on RHEL.

Usually the base image doesn't really matter much in terms of compatibility with your system, in case you're worried about this. The userland (libs/bins) that the containerized process (db2) gets to use are all provided by the container, whereas the host's kernel is directly accessible to the process (unless you're using another security layer, like Kata Containers). This is the reason why containers offer consistent environments while being really lightweight. The isolation offered means that you do not need to worry about differences between host and container OS, unless your containerized app needs a specific kernel version.

Regarding stability and security RHEL should be a good choice as a base image though. If you really need Ubuntu for some reason, you will either need to look for an unofficial image providing db2 (if there is one and it is somewhat trustworthy...) or you'll need to build your own db2-image based on Ubuntu.

In conclusion I would recommend to simply use the RHEL-based image, unless it doesn't let you use some very specific features. In this case you still have the option to build your own image (create a Dockerfile and build).

Comment: Thanks，i have convicted myself to try to use Redhat-base image.